# Wordpress or Drupal Users Report Module

Tags: wordpress, drupal, module

I have to build a site that receives some custom report from my users and store them in a database. The users are able to view their reports and the department administrator comments on it. I was creating this myself using PHP although it was good but it's full of security holes and I get lost after a while when my code grows bigger.
I think if there is a module for drupal or wordpess that can benefit from grouping my users into separate groups that would be much easier.
Does anyone know if there is such plugin or would you recommend me some keywords to search with.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like Drupal would be a good fit for this. There would be (at least) two roles (one for regular users and one for administrators), and there would be a 'report' content type. Regular users would be able to upload reports and view their own reports and administrators would be able to comment on reports.

Drupal + [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) (and possibly the [FileField](http://drupal.org/project/filefield) module if users are uploading document files) would be able to handle all of this pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal with the CCK & FileField modules would work great (as Mike mentioned). Two roles would suffice (admin & regular user).

As for security, make sure to use the latest versions in Drupal 6 & stay on top of when those 2 modules get updated although Drupal makes it super easy for you through site notification. Along the lines of security, you'd want to 'hide' the login box from the homepage & use www.sitename.com/user for your users to login.